# F# "This value is not a function and cannot be applied" when trying to add (+)

Tags: f#

The `m.Count + m.StepSize` in the F# code, 4th line from the bottom, returns the error `This value is not a function and cannot be applied`.

I can't see why `+` isn't being interpreted as an infix function instead of `m.Count`.

Why is this line a problem?

```
type Model =
    { Count: int
      StepSize: int }

type Msg =
    | Increment
    | Decrement
    | SetStepSize of int
    | Reset

let init =
    { Count = 0
      StepSize = 1 }

let canReset = (<>) init

let update msg m =
    match msg with
    | Increment -> { m with Count = m.Count + m.StepSize }
    | Decrement -> { m with Count = m.Count - m.StepSize }
    | SetStepSize x -> { m with StepSize = x }
    | Reset -> init
```

Comment: The code you provided compiles and runs fine for me. I tested it like this: `update Increment init |> printfn "%A"` and it correctly incremented `Count`. Perhaps you've redefined `+` somewhere?

Comment: I am aware that I must `let (+)`... somewhere to do that and I don't think I am.  I rarely overload operators like that.  I'll triple check of course.  Thank you.

Comment: Change `update` to `let update (msg: Msg) (m: Model) : Model =` and see what happens. I expect you will get a more understandable compile error.

Comment: If you are doing this in F# interactive, the redefined operator may also be a leftover from some earlier experimentation. Restarting that may help :)